# How do I visually select the block of text I just pasted in Vim?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

I usually need to move/copy code snippets between my source files. After I paste a block of text, I usually need to apply some operation to that block such as reindenting them with `=`.

Is there a way to easily visually select the block of text I just pasted without doing it manually?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `'[` and `']` marks delimit the first and last line of the previously changed or yanked text.  The `` `[ `` and `` `] `` counterparts delimit the respective lines & columns.

Using that, you could visually select the last changed block of lines with <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and then apply the `=` command.

However, since a paste leaves your cursor at the first line of the content that was pasted, you could also just specify a motion over which the `=` command should be applied, in this case to the `']` mark.  This would be <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: This answer describes a method that works for all types of visual selections (including blockwise visual): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312664/is-there-a-vim-command-to-select-pasted-text

Answer (score 17):

This mapping allows you to reselect the text you just pasted:

```
nnoremap gV `[v`]
```

But you should have used `[p` and `]p` instead.

See `:help [p`.

Comment: +1 for `[p` and `]p`

Answer (score 3):

Vim includes the following helpful mappings:

```
`[
```

and

```
`]
```

Which select the first and last character of previously changed text, respectively.

The following series of keys (in normal mode) will select the last pasted text:

```
`[v`]
```

For faster access, you could set up a mapping, [for example](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Selecting_your_pasted_text):

```
nnoremap gp `[v`]
```