# Is there a way to reselect the last visual shape, rather than the last actual selection, starting at the current cursor position?

Tags: visual-mode

I know that gv reselects the last visual selection. This is great and I use it frequently.

But sometimes I want to do something related but different: from the current cursor position, select a block in the same shape as the prior visual selection, but *positioned* where the cursor is now.

In particular, I often have this desire when pasting a chunk of text and then wanting to do some sort of substitution or transformation to it. So this command would let me reselect what I just pasted. (For that reason, also useful would be a command to "visually select last paste," but there are nonetheless other instances where what I literally want is "reselect last visual shape irrespective of whether that reselects the last paste." **EDIT: Please see [Is there a way to reselect the last pasted text, rather than the last actual selection, starting at the current cursor position?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/is-there-a-way-to-reselect-the-last-pasted-text-rather-than-the-last-actual-sel) for this question**)

(Note: if there is not a built-in way to do this, I'm comfortable editing ~/.vim to add a vimscript example [and possibly modify it] and bind this to an easy key combination, but writing one from scratch to do this is beyond my present ability.)

Comment: You could do a macro ..

Comment: This is a good idea (I assume you mean something like qpv[select...]q[move...]@p") but it doesn't really get at what I want, since in normal course of use I want to operate in visual mode, then only "realize" that I want the selection again after the paste operation. I'm looking for a few keystrokes to help in that circumstance, though I agree this is useful if I am operating slowly enough to anticipate needing to reselect the region.

Comment: Actually there's another case where this isn't possible: pasting from outside vim (e.g. via the * register). In this case the question should be as in the parenthetical: is there a motion to visually select the last paste? This is useful e.g. for sending example code from Stackexchange from vim to a REPL.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you want - to remember the "coordinates" of last paste, *before* further changes, in order to reselect them easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple remap that allows you to re-select last pasted (or changed) text:

```
noremap gV `[v`]
```

From comments in original post, perhaps you want to save the coordinates of the last change/paste *before* other/further changes, and restore *that* visual selection?

Comment: OK yes, tested this and it works; this is great. Really this is my fault for asking two related questions in one. I think what I'll do is change this question to be the one you've correctly answered here, and then re-ask the related question as a separate question, unless a mod has a better idea.

Comment: Actually that question is asked and answered here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-do-i-visually-select-the-block-of-text-i-just-pasted-in-vim?rq=1 Sorry--my fault for making a mess.

Answer (score 6):

To reselect the old shape, you can do this:

```
1v
```

Comment: It doesn't reselect the same shape, but the same number of characters.

Comment: Tested this and it also seems to work with the caveat @muru notes. In most instances when the re-select is not for selecting pasted text but recreating a selection then correctly positioning the cursor will imply that selecting the same number of characters will recreate the same shape. BUT, I can imagine exceptions. So still curious about an alternative approach that duplicates the shape. Maybe this is impossible in circumstances where lines don't have the same length.