# Is there a way to reselect the last pasted text, rather than the last actual selection, starting at the current cursor position?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

I know that gv reselects the last visual selection. This is great and I use it frequently.

But sometimes I want to select the block of text that I just pasted. This is useful e.g. for sending example code from Stackexchange from vim to a REPL or generally selecting text that I just pasted from one tab to another or from outside vim to inside, etc.

**NOTE**: I am asking this question just to provide the right place to put the answer to a related question to [Is there a way to reselect the last visual shape, rather than the last actual selection, starting at the current cursor position?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/is-there-a-way-to-reselect-the-last-visual-shape-rather-than-the-last-actual-se)